# What is the Method for Database CleanUp in SQlite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net

As what i experience using Sqlite for my Small Applications i always use **sqliteadmin** to use its database *cleanup* function to removes unnecessary data on my database.

Now i want to create a Method in my Application which do the same way as sqliteadmin  **CleanUp**.

How to do this?

Thanks in Regards

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems you're looking for the [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) statement.

Answer (score 43):

```
using (SQLiteCommand command = m_connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "vacuum;";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

here is the exact answer on how to execute vacuum.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting post script.  The Vacuum statement in SQLite copies the entire database to a temp file for rebuilding.  If you plan on doing this "On Demand" via user or some process, it can take a considerable amount of disk space and time to complete once your database gets above 100MB, especially if you are looking at several GB.  In that case, you are better off using the AUTO_VACUUM=true pragma statement when you create the database, and just deleting records instead of running the VACUUM.  So far, this is the only advantage I can find that SQL Server Compact has over SQLite. On demand SHRINK of the Sql Server Compact database is extremely fast compared to SQLite's vacuum.

Comment: Have not had the time to try it yet, but this pragma looks nice. However, since this is not the default, one should look at the exact behaviour here: http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum

Comment: Also, the arguments may not be simply "true" or "false", but rather  "0,1,2,NONE,FULL,INCREMENTAL".